# Display time down to milliseconds in Ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby, time

I'm trying to get my application to show time down to the milliseconds (e.g. 11:37:53.231), but `strftime` in 1.8.7 doesn't seem to have an option for it (http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Time.html#method-i-strftime). In Ruby >= 1.9.3, there's the %3N option (http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime), but it's not in the docs for 1.8.7, and doesn't seem to work either.

This is the output I get in Ruby 1.8.7.

```
cur_time = Time.now
# => Mon Jun 24 12:43:14 +0900 2013
cur_time.strftime('%H:%M:%S.%3N')
# => "12:43:14.%3N"
```

Is there alternative solution? Unfortunately, moving to 1.9.3 isn't an option.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
class Time
  def to_milliseconds
    (self.to_f * 1000.0).to_i
  end
end
```

Then

```
some_time = Time.now
some_time.to_milliseconds # Time in milliseconds. It will be a big number

some_time.strftime("%H:%M:%S.#{some_time.to_milliseconds % 1000}") # Same as some_time.strftime('%H:%M:%S.%3N')
```

Comment: This answer seems to put the seconds as part of the milliseconds too. Something like `((time_diff - time_diff.to_i) * 1000.0).to_i` inside the `to_milliseconds` formula would help provide only the milliseconds at the end.

Comment: for miliseconds between 0 and 99, you need to add .to_s.rjust(3, '0') to my previous code (can't edit).

Comment: monkey patching is bad bro.

Comment: @jahrichie yes, it's often a bad idea, but you don't *have* to monkey patch `Time`, you can easily add the method to your own class. It's just an example :)

Answer (score 38):

I think you might be looking for "%L", which will give you milliseconds in three digits.

```
cur_time.strftime('%H:%M:%S.%L')     #=> "12:34:56.789"
```

However, I'm not sure if this is supported in older versions of Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

Based on this:
A microsecond is equal to 1000 nanoseconds or 1/1,000 milliseconds
You could get microsecond first by :

```
tv_usec => int
```

Returns just the number of microseconds for time.

```
t = Time.now        #=> Wed Apr 09 08:56:04 CDT 2003

"%10.6f" % t.to_f   #=> "1049896564.259970"

t.usec              #=> 259970
```

And then divide by 1000

Answer (score 1):

FWIW my solution to this was

```
time = Time.now #could be any time object
ms = time.to_f.to_s.split(".").last[0..2]
time.strftime("%H:%M:%S.#{ms}")
```

Comment: That's an ugly way of doing it, since as @Keane_zhou has pointed out, you could simply use `time.strftime("%H:%M:%S.#{time.usec/1000}")`.

Answer (score 0):

A small refactoring to the answer provided by NicoSantangelo:

```
class Time
  def to_millisecond
     ((self.to_f * 1000.0).to_i) % 1000
  end
end
```

Then you can use it like this in order to generate a WS-security complaint timestamp:

```
time = Time.now
soap_timestamp = time.strftime("%FT%T.#{time.to_millisecond}Z")
```

Or you can use it as needed in your example...